# Why UserDefaults data is not loading when app starts?

Tags: swiftui, userdefaults

Data saved is working fine but when app starts, it initializes the events as empty but doesn’t load UserDefaults data using the code below. Any ideas ?

```
import SwiftUI

class TaskData: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var tasks: [Task] = [Task].init()
    
    static let saveKey = "Saved Data"
    
    init() {
    if let data = UserDefaults.standard.data(forKey: Self.saveKey) {
        do {
            if let decoded = try JSONDecoder().decode([Event]?.self, from: data) {
                self.events = decoded
                print("Loaded Data")
                print(self.events)
                return
            }
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
}
    
    func delete(_ task: Task) {
        events.removeAll { $0.id == task.id }
        save()
    }
    
    func add(_ task: Task) {
        tasks.append(task)
        save()
    }
    
    func save() {
        if let encoded = try? JSONEncoder().encode(tasks) {
            UserDefaults.standard.set(encoded, forKey: Self.saveKey)
            print("Saved")
            print(encoded)
        }
    }
    
    func exists(_ task: Task) -> Bool {
        tasks.contains(task)
    }
   …
```

I understand the init to load data from userDefaults above should load data and insert into tasks but it doesn’t at app in foreground or opened.

Comment: While developing code it's highly recommended to catch and print all errors.

Comment: This `init()` function will be called when you create an instance of `TaskData`, not necessarily at "app in foreground or opened". Check that you are creating an instance of that object, then show us some debugging you've done: what is the content of `decoder`? Is `data` loading something, or it's empty?

Comment: @vadian, there are no errors catched at this point, I just included the code required to request the help from the team here.

Comment: @HunterLion, instance of TaskData is being created as `@StateObject` into Taskapp (App struct) and `decoder` content is the data from tasks, I could see that. I noticed that when app starts, `init()` is executed creating the array but the `init()` to load the saved data is not executed at this time so array keep empty.

Comment: Of course , `try?` doesn't catch errors, it ignores them. Add a `do - catch` block and `print` the error

Comment: Did it as you have mentioned and the error is:

Loaded Data
[]
Saved
255 bytes
valueNotFound(Swift.String, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [_JSONKey(stringValue: "Index 0", intValue: 0), CodingKeys(stringValue: "color", intValue: nil)], debugDescription: "Expected String but found null value instead.", underlyingError: nil)). I updated the code above with the `do catch` as I’m using now. Any idea ?

Comment: Yes, the error is clear. The value of `color` can be `null` so declare it as (optional) `String?`